# The scrollbar of the child HorizontalScrollView has been separated from the scrollbar of the parent ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview, scrollbars

I'm studying android `ScrollView`.
But, I have a problem.

The scrollbar of the child `HorizontalScrollView` has been separated from the scrollbar of the parent `ScrollView`.
I have to combine two scrollbars of both `ScrollViews`.
I tried searching for the solution.
but it was failed
or, please tell me other ways to solve this problem.

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.project.talktalk.tulre.HomeActivity"
    android:id="@id/container">

        <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="new recipe"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recipeRecycler"
                    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabRecipe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_restaurant_white_24px"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="add recipe" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/darkgray"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/darkgray"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ScrollView you have `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`. Set it to false and it will remove the scrollbars from the child views of the ScrollView and give you the behaviour you desire. If you have nested ScrollViews you should consider using `NestedScrollView` instead as nested ScrollViews are considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried it you said. but it's the same as before.